# How to add to array text file in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

This might be a simple question but its irking me. I have been making pace with a program that adds zoo animals to a text file in a list, and I am trying to let the user add a new animal to it if it isn't on there, but the way I'm setting  it (userInput = names[i]) is not working. The code I'm trying to fill is:

```
cout << "What animal to add?" << endl;
                cin >> userAnimal;
                count = 0;
if (checkAnimal(userAnimal, names[MAX_SIZE]) == false)// checks if animal is 
                                                      //there
                {
                    cout << userAnimal << " is already in the array" << endl;

                }
                else {
         userAnimal = names[i] // insert userAnimal input into array
               }
            }
```

We are not allowed to include the append openings, which is what is making this difficult. I tried making names[MAX_SIZE] a vector, but then it seems to not allow it to be used to assign user input to it, nor does it let me assign it into a function or even read into an opened file. I also tried making a separate function which ultimately wouldn't let me use a vector.

EDIT: My goal is to add userAnimal to the end of my array variable, names[MAX_SIZE]. MAX_SIZE is 20. A text file was already read to names[MAX_SIZE] here:

```
ifIn.open("animals.txt");
    //checking whether the file name is valid or not
    if (ifIn.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error: File Not Found";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
//Reading the data from the file
        while (ifIn >> names[count])
        {
            for (int j = 0;j < 2;j++)
            {
                ifIn >> animalNumber[count][j];
            }
            count++;
        }
```

I apologize for the confusion. The simplest way I can ask this is how do I add user input to a text file without erasing anything nor using "append." names[MAX_SIZE] is my string array and it is what the text file was read to.

Thank you! I am new to coding, what a fun experience it is though!

Comment: I apologize, I meant to say I can't use it in assignment to user input, I'm trying to keep its value the same, but be able to add to it. I said bool because I am using the "==" operator to check if the animal already there, but if I turn it into a vector string then it won't let me.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've read this a couple of times but I have no idea what the issue actually is. Could you focus on the code that isn't working, post actual code, not a summary or a transcript. And the way the code isn't working (compiler errors, run time errors, unexpected results) with actual errors or output as appropriate.

Comment: I recommend transforming your response text to all lower case (std::tolower) or to all upper case (std::toupper) before comparison.  This will allow you to only use one comparison, instead of comparing for all permutations.  For example, your program doesn't handle the case of "aDd".

Comment: Deja Vu!  The "if" condition is the same as the "else-if" condition!

Comment: I edited the question, I was trying to show everything that I believe possibly could have been changed so I could add to the text file "animals.txt"